# Probability density function and exp distr

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, exponential-function

I'm going through preparatory tasks for an exam, but I'm stuck on a particular problem.

pdf(x) = $c\cdot e^{-3x}$, where $x \ge 0$ and $0$ for any other value of $x$

I worked out the constant to 3.

A) $Pr(X > a), a > 0$

B) $Pr(X > a+b\mid X > b)$

I worked out A) to be $e^{-3a}$, and since B) is an exponential distribution problem, I simplified it to $Pr(X > a)$, giving me the same answer as A). Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability you want is $P(X>a+b|X>b)$ where $X$ has an exponential distribution.

Using the CDF of the exponential distribution...

$$ P(X\leq a+b|X>b) = \frac{P(X\leq a+b\cap X > b) }{P(X>b)} = \frac{P(b< X \leq a+b)}{P(X>b)} = \frac{ e^{-b\lambda} - e^{(a+b)\lambda} }{e^{-b\lambda}}$$ 
$$=1 - e^{-a\lambda}$$

This means $$P(X>a+b|X>b) = 1- P(X \leq a+b | X> b ) = e^{-a \lambda}$$

This is true because the exponential has the property of being memoryless, i.e. previous events have no bearing on the current event. I've always found an interesting application of this in car batteries. Many studies have suggested car batteries to very closely approximate the exponential.

Comment: It's a similar problem but I'm not sure it answers my question.

Comment: @Enthusiast88 I fixed the constants, it should be good now.

Comment: Thanks, it looks more familiar now, but would you say substituting λ for the 3 provided in the function is a valid thing to do? Making the answer the same as in A)?

Comment: @Enthusiast88 The pdf of the exponential distribution is defined generally to be pdf(x) = $\lambda e^{-\lambda x}$ for all $x \ge 0$, $0$ otherwise.

Comment: So when I am provided with 3*e^(-3x), is the 3 inside the exponent the λ in the formula?

Comment: @Enthusiast88 Yes...? Why would it not be? Compare the generalized pdf to your answer. If you doubt this fact, I would recommend looking up the proof of the generalized formula. It may be enlightening.